# sql script works on MySQL, but not on google bigquery

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have sql scripts that work fine in MySQL, but that I cannot get to work in google bigquery.  After reading through bq documentation, I made a number of adjustments (eg no more than one join per select statement), but the script still fails.  Any help is appreciated.  If you know of any good resources in terms of bq sql vs other sql, that would also be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
SELECT 
T1.action_date AS action_date,
T1.ad_campaign_category AS ad_campaign_category,
T1.campaign_id AS campaign_id,
T2.total_sends AS total_sends, 
count(*) AS clicks_per_category
FROM ( 
    SELECT action_date, campaign_id, ad_campaign_category
    FROM projectX.email_action
    WHERE action_date > '2009-04-01' AND action_date < '2011-05-01') T1,

    (
    SELECT action_date, campaign_id, ad_campaign_category, count(*) AS total_sends
    FROM projectX.email_action
    WHERE action_type = 'send' AND action_date > '2009-04-01' AND action_date < '2011-05-01'
    GROUP BY action_date, campaign_id) T2

WHERE T1.action_date = T2.action_date 
    AND T1.campaign_id = T2.campaign_id
GROUP BY action_date, campaign_id, ad_campaign_category
```

Comment: Is there a particular error message you're running into?

Comment: The answer below corrected the problem.  Here was the error message:  Error: Unknown field: T1.action_date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JOIN must be explicit -- that is, rather than using `SELECT ... FROM (...) t1, (...) t2 WHERE t1.x = t2.y` you should use the form `SELECT ... FROM (...) t1 JOIN (...) t2 ON t1.x = t2.y`
For your example, this would look like:

```
SELECT 
T1.action_date AS action_date,
T1.ad_campaign_category AS ad_campaign_category,
T1.campaign_id AS campaign_id,
T2.total_sends AS total_sends, 
count(*) AS clicks_per_category
FROM ( 
    SELECT action_date, campaign_id, ad_campaign_category
    FROM projectX.email_action
    WHERE action_date > '2009-04-01' AND action_date < '2011-05-01') T1
JOIN (
    SELECT action_date, campaign_id, ad_campaign_category, count(*) AS total_sends
    FROM projectX.email_action
    WHERE action_type = 'send' AND action_date > '2009-04-01' AND action_date < '2011-05-01'
    GROUP BY action_date, campaign_id) T2
ON T1.action_date = T2.action_date 
AND T1.campaign_id = T2.campaign_id
GROUP BY action_date, campaign_id, ad_campaign_category
```

Note if you get an error that one of the tables is too large, try using `JOIN EACH` instead of `JOIN`.